# Not able to verify mobile number on twitter

Tags: twitter

I am not able to verify my mobile number on twitter. Its showing me error:


Sorry, we don’t have a connection to your mobile provider yet!
Don’t worry, we’re on it and will let you know once things are set up. In the meantime, use one of our long codes. Learn more (https://support.twitter.com/articles/14226-how-to-find-your-twitter-short-code-or-long-code)

Please help me since i want write access to my twitter application and will not be able to set write access until i verify my mobile number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your smartphone for this purpose.
Install twitter app on your smartphone first.
then follow instruction on the website: 

http://www.cyberfan.cf/twitter-mobile-verification-error/

Comment: Please include relevant information from links in the answer itself. Links change and die.